# Haskell Gnuplot not responding to title function

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

I'm attempting to add a title to a plot made with Gnuplot in Haskell.  While the program produces a graph in a stand-alone window it creates, I can't seem to get it to respond to the title function.  Am I using the title function incorrectly?

I'm using Stack, with

```
 - only "-gnuplot" added to the "dependencies:" section of package.yaml
 - resolver: lts-15.7 in an unmodified stack.yaml.
```

on a computer running Linux Mint 19.  The code and a screen shot of the pop-up window are:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.Gnuplot.Advanced
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Plot.TwoDimensional as P2D
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Graph.TwoDimensional as G2D
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Terminal.X11 as X11

zeroToTen = [0.0, 0.1 .. 10.0 :: Double]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  plot (X11.title "My Title" X11.cons) (P2D.function G2D.lines zeroToTen sin)
  _  <- getLine
  return ()
```

[image: screen shot of the pop-up window the program creates]

Comment: But you import this from `Terminal`. I did not use `X11` (yet), but shouldn't this convert the title of the console/terminal, instead of the window?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that it changed anything.  Perhaps I just don't know where to look for the title?

Comment: I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.04. No trace of the title string anywhere. The only other graphical frontend in namespace `Graphics.Gnuplot.Terminal` that has a title function is `WXT`, and using that one, the title also doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in gnuplot (the package). The following is the code block where the options for an X11 terminal are built into `gnuplot`-parseable command-line parameters:

File: X11.hs

```
-- Part of a record update, hence the trailing comma
Terminal.options =
     "x11" :
     catMaybes (
           (fmap quote $ title_ term) :
        (fmap (formatBool "persist") $ persist_ term) :
        []),
```

On the third last line, the `title_ :: Maybe String` field of the `term` record is surrounded by quotes by the `quote` function (just an alias of `show`). The issue is that in order to be parsed by `gnuplot`, it should also be prepended with `title`  ([see manual](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node442.html)). Until it gets fixed, you can always configure gnuplot [as a local package](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps) and build it from there.

Here is the fix (line 43 of X11.hs):

```
(fmap (("title " ++) . quote) $ title_ term) :
```

[image: Working screenshot]

By the way, there is a more optimal way to import packages. Writing `import X as Y` means: "import everything into the global namespace, but also give me Y as an alias for the imported symbols". A better way is `import qualified X as Y`, which fences the imported module into the `Y` namespace.

*Final note*
If you try and build gnuplot on your own, you'll find that `gnuplot` doesn't compile because of a couple of missing `Semigroup` instances caused by the "Semigroup-Monoid" proposal in GHC 8.4. The way to fix this is simply to add a `Semigroup` instance that refers to the `mappend` method from the `Monoid` instance:

```
import Data.Semigroup
instance Semigroup Script where
  (<>) = mappend
```

Comment: Thank you.  I implemented this on my machine and it also works for me.